# Watermark using FFMpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

I am using FFMpeg to add a watermark to a 30min video. Therefore, I used the following code:

`ffmpeg -i video1.avi -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:1O" test1.avi`

However, the output is just a 5min video with worse quality. How can I fix this issue?

Thank you very much for your help!

PD: After I ran that line of code I got this message:

````
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 67.100 / 56. 67.100
  libavcodec     58.129.100 / 58.129.100
  libavformat    58. 71.100 / 58. 71.100
  libavdevice    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavfilter     7.109.100 /  7.109.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from 'video1.avi':
  Duration: 00:05:04.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1198 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1280x720, 1050 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15 tbn, 30 tbc
  Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
Input #1, png_pipe, from 'watermark.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 198x106 [SAR 7558:7558 DAR 99:53], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'test1.avi' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] Y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (mpeg4)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0000019bed8db300] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, avi, to 'test1.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.71.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.129.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 8000 Hz, mono, s16p
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.129.100 libmp3lame
frame= 3041 fps=228 q=31.0 Lsize=    8590kB time=00:05:04.06 bitrate= 231.4kbits/s speed=22.8x
video:8075kB audio:297kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.593717%```
````

Comment: The video is probed as 5 mins long: `Input #0, avi, from 'video1.avi':
  Duration: 00:05:04.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1198 kb/s`

Comment: How could I change that? I did not set it that way in my code.

Comment: The duration of the input is detected, not set, so there' s nothing to change.

Comment: @0tonin How did you determine the duration is 30 minutes and not 5?

Comment: @llogan if i play the original video with VLC media player is 30min not 5. I dont know if it could be that the avi file is corrupted or something and this is why it only processes 5min.

Comment: Without access to the file there isn't much we can suggest.